# Heap sort using only insert and remove?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, heap, heapsort

I am doing an review on my Algorithm exam, and here's a problem I found in old exam without sample solution. I am not sure what would be a reasonable answer to this question:

```
Using a heap and its two operations Remove and Insert,  design an algorithm which sorts an array of size n in O(nlogn) time.
```

To me, this problem looks like a simple heap-sorting problem, and I think my answer is just:

 - 1) Insert every element in to a min heap

 - 2) remove everything in the heap from the top and put them in a array in order...

Not sure this is what they want, anyone has any idea please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are on right track. See [here](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/fall10/lectures/lec09.pdf), slide 39.